# Web-App automatically choose Login method: WIF-ADFS or manual

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, wif, adfs

I am developing a website using asp .net and i give the users two possibilities to log in.
The first is using WIF-ADFS and the second is through manual input.

The thing is, i want the application to check whether it is possible for a certain user to use SSO.
If yes, do SSO, if no, make the application choose the second login possibility automatically.

The question is whether it is possible to implement my application to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answers is: probably not if you do not have a "list" of all users with all of their authentication options/methods. There for you have to present them the options (aka WAYF or HRD)....

WIF + ADFS use WS-FED, and the implementations have no graceful fall back. The ADFS server just display an error page. The older ADFS version had some limited options to fix it. The newer ADFS on S2012R2 cannot be extended/customized (except when it is possible in JavaScript on the client side).

Answer (score 0):

If a user want's to log in you have at first no automatic mechanism to determine if he can do SSO (besides you can control all browsers in question and add something to their UserAgent) or not.

So all what is left is to display a form for login with local data and some buttons for login with ADFS or Google or Facebook or whatever.

Microsoft does this in Azure Authentication Services, Thinktecture supports it with the IdentityServer (I think) and MVC has a template for actions like that (and you can use ASP.NET Identity V2 with that).